# How to pass a map into an action

Tags: smart-contract, development, contract-development

I'm trying to pass a map into action, but there is serialization error:

```
Error: expected object containing data: undefined
```

There is a function signature:

```
void init(uint64_t id, const map<uint8_t, asset>& balances);
```

There is tx data I pass:

```
data: {
    id: id,
    balances: {0: "1.0000 EOS", 1: "1.0000 TOKEN"}
}
```

I also tried this tx data:

```
data: {
    id: id,
    balances: [{0: "1.0000 EOS"}, {1: "1.0000 TOKEN"}]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

balances field should look like `[{'key': 1, 'value': '1.0000 EOS'}]`